# Count if with Multiple Criterias

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, countif

My table has 2 columns:

- 1 column: seller
- 2 column: NEW or Repeat

Inside the seller column, we have names like Juan, Pedro, Miguel.
I want to count the number of NEW cars that Juan and Pedro have sold.

I know it should be with a COUNTIFS function but haven't been able to build it.

Could someone help me with this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap in SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"Juan","Pedro"},B:B,"New"))
```

Comment: @JVA if it worked for you, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: What if I would have now another column ( age of the car ) and I need to count only the ones that are equal or greater than 1990?

Comment: just add `,C:C,">=1990"`